# Do shields from multiple Symmetras stack?

Tags: overwatch

As the title says, if there are multiple Symmetras on my team, can they both shield teammates for a total of 50 extra health, or can only one shield take effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this guide [here](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/symmetra.html), the answer would be no, so you can't add an extra 125 shields by running 5 Symmetras.

> Only one shield per ally.  This also means multiple Symmetras cannot stack shields.